# Jfree charts Labels overlapping

Tags: jfreechart

I am using Area Chart to draw the temperatures from database but as the data grows chart labels start getting merge. Please help me to get it fixed.

Comment: Hi @Rafay, welcome!, you should edit your question showing a small reproducible piece of code, in order to help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JFreeChart doesn't do any overlap detection for Area Chart. You have to implement your own Customizer and you can design an algo to skip some lables by just making them transparent.

You have to create the class and implement

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRChartCustomizer
```

and write the logic in overridden method called `customize`. For example if you want to print label after 8th iteration then do as the done in the below code for reference.

```
@Override
public void customize(org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart chart, net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRChart jasperChart) {
    org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.AreaRenderer renderer;
    org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot plot;
    org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis rangeAxis;
    org.jfree.chart.axis.CategoryAxis axis;
    renderer = (org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.AreaRenderer) chart.getCategoryPlot().getRenderer();

    plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
    rangeAxis = (org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();

    axis = plot.getDomainAxis();

    CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
    CategoryLabelPositions pos = domainAxis.getCategoryLabelPositions();
     for (int i = 1; i <= plot.getCategories().size(); i++) {
                    if(i%8==0){
                    continue;
                    } else{
                        String cat_Name = (String) plot.getCategories().get(i-1);
                     domainAxis.setTickLabelPaint(cat_Names, new Color(0,0,0,0));
                       }
           }
       }
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution is great. I need one more thing . It fixed my major problem of overlapping but still getting overlap from the end. How to fix that.

Comment: @Rafay I just Proposed the solution to avoid overlapping, Now the problem may be  is with your algorithm  you can restrict it by defining max range so that after that range skip  
all the iterations and print last label.

Comment: If it is helpful please accept the solution.